# Type casting in Hibernate for column in Informix database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring, informix

I am using Informix for a OR database and Spring + Hibernate on the backend of my application.
The thing is, I make in a String variable the query that inserts data in the database table. In this query string I'm using type casting for some columns (something like this: `..ROW(street,city,country)::addressT..` where addressT is the type I made in the database).

The problem here lays in Hibernates `createSQLQuery(String query)` method. When I pass it the query string, it automatically searches in that string for named parameters (:namedParameter - so the "colon" sign and the name of the parameter) and tries to replace it with something.
The result is a query like this: `...ROW(street,city,country)?...`

Is there any way to disable hibernates automatic named parameter replacement or is there any other way to forward the native query to my Informix database?

Comment: Ok, i found a workaround... In informix database I made a cast_addresst(a1 varchar(30),a2 varchar(30),a3 varchar(30)) function which construct a ROW, casts it to my type and returns it, and in Java code I just call this funcion in the string query. Maybe someone will find it usefull..

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `CAST(<expression> AS <type>)` notation.

Beware of other system's adamant insistence that '`db@server:owner.table`' or '`DATETIME(12:13:14) YEAR TO SECOND`' contain placeholders, not legitimate Informix syntactic constructs.